# javafx stretch an image to fill a button?

Tags: image, button, javafx

I am writing a "Star Trek" game for fun with Java/JavaFX.  My idea is that the main game screen is an 10x10 GridPane of Buttons.  All the game pieces (the Enterprise, Klingons, planets, etc) would appear as icons in the buttons.  This way, you can click a space object to select it, warp to it, shoot it, etc:

[image: My Game Image Concept]

Of course, this is all contingent on being able to assign my little starship images to the appropriate buttons.  I've figured out how to apply a background to a button, but when I apply the image, the fit is not good.  Here's a screenshot of my game thus far:

[image: My game interface thus far]

The "Enterprise" image sorta fits... but not really.  There's got to be a way to stretch the ship to fit the button ***exactly***, but I've yet to find it.  I also have to find a way to do this in Java (not CSS or FXML) because the Java code will have to move icons around.

Here's my code:

```
public void setUpBoard(){

  // set up 10x10 GridPane of Buttons...

  Image testImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Enterprise.png"));
  ImageView testImageView = new ImageView(testImage);
  testImageView.setFitWidth(55);            // My button is 55 x 37 pixels, according to the FXML
  testImageView.setFitHeight(37);
  //testImageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(gridButton37.widthProperty());   // This didn't work either
  //testImageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(gridButton37.widthProperty());
  gridButton37.setGraphic(testImageView);
}
```

I've been Googling for a few hours, but I can't find a "stretch image to parent" solution that seems to apply here.  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Seems to me like you didn't. Using a [`BackgroundImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundImage.html) with the appropriate parameters as one of the `Background`'s parts ([see `background` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#backgroundProperty)) allows you to stretch the image to a specified size. Alternatively you could specify the appropriate size for the `Image` when loading or use `fitWidth`/`fitHeight` and don't preserve the aspect ratio with the `ImageView`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    btnTest.setMinSize(55, 37);
    btnTest.setMaxSize(55, 37);

    Image image = new Image("/view/images/someImage.png", btnTest.getWidth(), btnTest.getHeight(), false, true, true);
    BackgroundImage bImage = new BackgroundImage(image, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, new BackgroundSize(btnTest.getWidth(), btnTest.getHeight(), true, true, true, false));

    Background backGround = new Background(bImage);
    btnTest.setBackground(backGround);
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Background.html

Comment: Also, if I may suggest, you can implement your backGround as an Enum (since, you'll have to set these to different Buttons, according to your game rules).

Comment: --  Thanks, that did the trick.  I had read (really: skimmed) through the documentation you provided, but I honestly didn't see how to directly apply it to my situation.  A little help goes a looooooooong way sometimes.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure how this works, but that line of code fixes the problem:

```
yourButton.setPadding(new Insets(-1, -1, -1, -1));
```